# Uploading a file to a ftp server fails

Tags: c#, ftp, stream, filestream, ftpwebrequest

I have a small C# winform in which I generate some text files and then move them to an ftp server.
When I try to move them to the production server it fails under

> The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.

If I log in to the ftp via cmd/ftp with the same ftp address, username and password, everything is ok. I also installed a local ftp server on my machine and tested it to see if perhaps my code is generating the error, but locally it works like a charm, I have the problem only with the production ftp server. 
Below is my code to connect and upload the files to the ftp server:

```
string[] FileName = Directory.GetFiles(outputpath);

foreach (string txtFile in FileName)
{
     FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo(txtFile);

     FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + tbFTPAddress.Text + @"//" + toUpload.Name);

     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tbFTPUserName.Text.Trim(), tbFTPPassword.Text.Trim());

     request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

     Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     FileStream file = File.OpenRead(txtFile);

     int length = 1024;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
     int bytesRead = 0;

     try
     {
         do
         {
             bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
             ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
         while (bytesRead != 0);

         file.Close();
         ftpStream.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error encountered!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
     finally
     {
         if (file != null) file.Close();
         if (ftpStream != null) ftpStream.Close();
     }
}
```

The error comes at: `Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that the password contains the * char. Can this be a problem?

Comment: did you try this with a different external ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call GetResponse() at first.

```
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        try
        {
            //You have to call this or you would be unable to get a stream :)
            WebResponse response = fwr.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(localfile), FileMode.Open);
        byte[] fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();

        //Now you are able to open a Stream
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        request.Abort();
```

Comment: Hello Marcel, thank you for your feedback, but now, even on my local ftp server it fails under `The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).` at `Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();` Here is the modified code as per your suggestion: `request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
try
{
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
{
throw ex;
}
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(txtFile);`

Comment: Also, let me add AGAIN that locally, the code works and creates/moves the files. So I don't think that the problem comes from the missing GetResponse() call.

Comment: sounds like a strange problem :). Does the remote FTP run with same settings? If not check out your configuration. Maybe the remote server use sftp or has other restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by same settings? Unfortunatelly, the production ftp server that I am trying to move the files to, belongs to a partner company and I can not get any additional information on it except the username and password they already provided us with. If it is indeed an SFTP server, would it make any difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too.  (You do not need to get the response first.)  In my case, it was a problem of folder permissions on the FTP server.

1. Remote in to your FTP server
2. Navigate to and right-click the folder/subfolder
3. Select properties
4. Switch to the Security tab
5. Click the Edit button
6. Make sure the IIS user account has write access